# How to Serialize different nested Serializes when the order is not allowing so

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

so I'm new to Django and I'm creating an API using djangorestframework

When creating the serializers I encountered a problem that I can't find a way to go around it.

I have 2 models, Site and Article
The site can have many articles
an article can have one site
I did the relationship in the models and everything looks fine.

When tried to serialize the information I started with the SiteSerializer which had a line to get the ArticleSerializer and had a related name of 'articles' (also the name of the variable) and it worked

But when trying to serialize the SiteSerializer inside the ArticleSerializer with the same way it cannot be done because the order of the classes, it cannot reference to it when it's yet to be created

CODE:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = SiteSerializer(many=false)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'url', 'summary', 'img', "published_date", 'site')


class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articles = ArticleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url', 'articles')
```

I can't reference to SiteSerializer when it's below, but it will be the opposite if I switch them up.

What can I do in this situation, is there another way to serialize different models with many to one or many to many relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have an infinite loop (Site > Articles > Site > Article, ...).
You can create 4 serializers :

```py
class NestedArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'url', 'summary', 'img', "published_date", 'site')


class SiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    articles = NestedArticleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url', 'articles')


class NestedSiteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    site = NestedSiteSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'url', 'summary', 'img', "published_date", 'site')
```

Comment: is it considered a good practice? it seems weird to double-write serializer for every model (I have more models in my app which also have similar relationships)

Comment: Your serializers are distinct since they do not exactly expose the same fields. This design let you adapt you serializers for each views which can be quite handy. Another way would be to use inheritance to have less code.

Comment: Alright, it seems right to have different serializer for model as I don't want to expose all the fields, thanks!

But, how can I do it with inheritance? nesting the whole serializer class inside each other?